# How to set `--expected-size` option in `boto3.client('s3').upload_fileobj()`?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli, data-stream

Since there is ability to set argument `--expected-size` in [aws s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) in order to ensure files/data larger than 5GB is uploaded successfully, how can it be set in python version of it: `boto3` [upload_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj)?

I'm trying to upload database backup as data stream to S3 without saving it to disk, but it fails in the middle of process due to `InvalidArgument: Part number must be an integer between 1 and 10000, inclusive`.

I assume it's because data stream is non-seekable so you have to set expected data size explicitly.

AWS CLI example:

```
innobackupex --stream=xbstream --compress /backup \
    | aws s3 cp - s3://backups/backup2018112 --expected-size=1099511627776
```

Boto3 example:

```
import subprocess
import boto3

innobackupexProc = subprocess.Popen([
    'innobackupex',
    '--stream=xbstream',
    '--compress',
    '/backup'
], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with innobackupexProc.stdout as dataStream:
    s3.upload_fileobj(dataStream, 'backups', 'backup2018112')
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm streaming files anywhere up to 100GB in size to S3, and don't know the total length in advance.  Some way to request a larger part-size would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to `upload_fileobj` using a default part size of 8 MiB. The file in your example CLI code is 1,099,511,627,776 bytes, which, with the default part size (8,388,608 bytes), results in 131,072 parts, way beyond the [maximum of 10,000 parts for Amazon S3 multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html).

The maximum part size is 5 GiB, so, as long as your file is less than S3's maximum object size of 5 TiB, you can just divide your total file size by 10,000 (rounding up) to get a part size that will work. In your example, this would be 109,951,163 bytes - about 105 MiB.

You can then set the part size for the multipart upload via `upload_fileobj`'s `Config` parameter:

```
import subprocess
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

# Amazon S3's maximum number of parts for multipart upload
MAX_PARTS = 10000

innobackupexProc = subprocess.Popen([
    'innobackupex',
    '--stream=xbstream',
    '--compress',
    '/backup'
], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Assuming expected_size holds the expected number of bytes.
# Just do integer division and add 1, rather than converting
# to floats and using math.ceil - it doesn't matter if the 
# result is one greater than it should be!
# Note - Python 3 changed how / works, so you'll need to use //
part_size = (expected_size / MAX_PARTS) + 1

config = TransferConfig(multipart_chunksize=part_size)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with innobackupexProc.stdout as dataStream:
    s3.upload_fileobj(dataStream, 'backups', 'backup2018112', Config=config)
```